# Error when installing Snort in Linux “Unable to locate package snort”

Tags: snort

I am trying to install Snort in Linux Ubuntu 20.04. Then I got this error "Unable to locate package snort". I tried to fix this error but I couldn't do it. Do I need to install Kali Linux before installing Snort? If not how can I solve this error in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I see `snort` available for all releases of Ubuntu; do you have 'universe' enabled?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: @guiverc I appreciate your help, but I have enabled 'universe' already. I searched for snort tutorials and all tutorial I have found in Kali Linux. That's why I thought Kali Linux mandatory for snort.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=snort&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all   so you should provide more details. If you `sudo apt update` do you get any errors?  I'd also check your chosen/selected mirror is *up-to-date* and doesn't have issues then.